# Yum is not installing msmtp

Tags: linux, centos, yum, msmtp

I am trying to install msmtp on my server CentOS 6.6. but yum says the package is not found.
I am using the default configuration for the yum came with the CentOS install.
how do I solve this?

Comment: find it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

msmtp is not available through standard Centos repo.
You'll need to install Epel repo first, pick one depending on your OS architecture.

For x86_64 system:

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

For x86 system:

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

You should be able to install msmtp now with:

```
yum install msmtp
```

Hope this helps,

Deeh

Comment: I was able to install it by downloading and compiling the source code. However I am having an error, when I am trying to send a mail with tls. msmtp complaining about "TLS not compiled in"

Comment: Recompile it with SSL
./configure --with-ssl=openssl

If that doesnt work: Telnet to your SMTP server port 25 and type "EHLO", make sure STARTTLS is listed. 

Furthermore, you can disable TLS in your msmtp config, but thats not recommended.

Let me know how it works out. Include msmtp config if you still have issues.

Comment: Thanks. Deeh, installed as you mentioned from the rpm. its worked fine. thank you. not able to vote you up.

Comment: I'm on Amazon Linux on AWS (CentOS 7 I believe) and run this command `sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install msmtp` - but I get dependency error `Error: Package: msmtp-1.4.32-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-keyring.so.0()(64bit)`. How can I fix that?

Comment: You're trying to install el6 (Centos6) RPM on a Centos7 OS.